# Citing only relevant articles from a .bbl file

Tags: bibtex

I have a `.bbl` file that contains a massive amount of entries (I don't have the related `.bib` file that generated it). Is it possible to tell LaTeX to include only the references/citations from `.bbl` file that are cited in the text and not everything (which is what happens if you "input" the `.bbl` file)?

MWE is below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\title{Your Paper}

\author{You}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Your abstract.
\end{abstract}

\input{test.bbl}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using BibTeX?

Comment: What you want to have should be the default behaviour. (Normally, the `.bbl` file gets generated by BibTeX from the `.bib` and contains only the entries that were actually used in the `.tex`) Can you post a MWE?

Comment: I am using this \input{supp.bbl} at the end of the document to include the .bbl

Comment: Please post a full minimal working example instead of throwing out little bits of information.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/4912864mzbxrx#/15127112/ would this do ?

Comment: You can manually comment the entries you are not  going use.

Comment: Well, the manual option is what I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: From what you write it looks as if you might have gotten something wrong about the use of bibtex. At last this seems to be a non-standard use of bibtex, so if people don't have to go through the hassle of creating a comparable situation to play around, they might be more willing to help. Could you create a minimal working example so that we can take closer a look at what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have added an example in overleaf in one of the previous comments. Yes, this is non-standard use.

Comment: Rather than post part of your question in overleaf where nobody can see your MWE unless they click through etc., please take the time to post the code you would like considered as part of the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `.bbl` file is well formed, that is

1. You only have `\bibitem{<tag>}`
2. There is no empty line in entries
3. Each entry (including the last one) is followed by a blank line

then you can use a trick involving the usage of `\citation` that's normally defined to do nothing.

### File `spokus-old.bbl`

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{Barker1998}
Chris Barker.
\newblock Partitives, double genitives and anti-uniqueness.
\newblock \emph{Natural Language \& Linguistic Theory}, 16:\penalty0 679--717,
  1998.

\bibitem{Berwick1985}
Robert~C. Berwick.
\newblock \emph{Acquisition of syntactic knowledge}.
\newblock MIT Press, Cambridge, MA, 1985.

\bibitem{Carlson1977}
Gregory~N. Carlson.
\newblock \emph{Reference to Kinds in {E}nglish}.
\newblock PhD thesis, University of Massachusetts, Amherst, 1977.

\bibitem{Carlson1995}
Gregory~N. Carlson and Francis~Jeffrey Pelletier, editors.
\newblock \emph{The Generic Book}.
\newblock Chicago University Press, Chicago, 1995.

\end{thebibliography}
```

### File `spokus.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\original@bibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem#1#2\par{%
  \@ifundefined{cited@#1}{}{\original@bibitem{#1}#2\par}%
}
\renewcommand\citation[1]{\global\@namedef{cited@#1}{}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\cite{Barker1998}

\cite{Carlson1977}

\input{spokus-old.bbl}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Explanation

Every `\cite` command writes a note in the aux file, in the form

```
\citation{<tag>}
```

Such note is normally only used by BibTeX, so it is defined to gobble its argument. We can redefine it to mark a label as used, which is the purpose of

```
\renewcommand\citation[1]{\global\@namedef{cited@#1}{}}
```

The `\bibitem` command is redefined to absorb the whole entry and then to see whether `\cited@<tag>` is defined; if it is, it outputs the entry, otherwise does nothing.